# Recover Trezor signature address but return other address

Tags: javascript, signature, trezor

I'm building a website (Nextjs) that allows user to login with Trezor wallet by signing Ethereum address.

In front-end, I used TrezorConnect to exported Ethereum addresses with path `m/44'/60'/0'/0/i` and sign message:

```
const message = await TrezorConnect.ethereumSignMessage({
        message: data,
        path: m/44'/60'/0'/0/0,
        hex: true,
});

await axios.post(`/login`, { signature: `0x${message.payload.signature}` });
```

In back-end (Nodejs), I used `eth-sig-util` to recover signature

```
const recoveredAddress = recoverPersonalSignature({
        data,
        sig: signature,
});

if (recoveredAddress.toLowerCase() !== expectedAddress.toLowerCase()) {
      throw new HttpException('Signature is not correct.', 400);
}
```

I saw that the `recoveredAddress` is different from `expectedAddress` that I used to sign message.
But when I used "Verify Message Signature" feature on [EtherScan](https://etherscan.io/verifiedSignatures), both were verified with same signature (that is `0x${message.payload.signature}`).

Are there other ways to verify Trezor signature?
I would be pleased if someone gives me any solutions.